# How can I assign a new action to an existing method?

Tags: c#, .net, class, methods, instance

I've created a class in C# which uses the method "Action".

```
public void Action()
{

}
```

The method is empty because, when a new instance of the class is created, the user should be able to define what the method does. One user may need the method to write to the console, another may want it to assign a value to a variable, etc. Is there any way for me to change what the method can do outside of its original definition, along the lines of the following:

```
//Using the instance "MyClass1", I have assigned a new action to it (Writing to the console)
//Now the method will write to the console when it is called
MyClass1.Action() = (Console.WriteLine("Action"));
```

Comment: You *may* want to look into delegates and anonymous methods. But this seems like a rather volatile way of executing code. Have you considered inheritance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way for me to change what the method can do outside of
>   its original definition

Not via "Named Methods" and the way you're using them in your example. If you want your class to be able to invoke a unit of execution defined by the user, you need to look either into inheritance hierarchy (as specified in @CodeCaster answer via virtual methods and overriding them), or perhaps look into [delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx).

You can use an [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.action%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) delegate:

```
public Action Action { get; set; }
```

Use it like so:

```
var class = new Class();
class.Action = () => { /*Code*/ }
```

And, when you want to invoke it:

```
if (class.Action != null)
{
   class.Action();
}
```

Comment: beat me to it by 2 seconds :)

Comment: Remember that when you're calling Action(), it could be null. And you can't use 'class' as an identifier.

Comment: @Dennis_E Added a nullity check :)

Comment: I think this answer is lacking some explanations. The question sounds a lot like the OP has the impression regular methods are variable entities whose implementation can be replaced at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

By making it abstract, inheriting the class and overriding the method.

```
public class FooBase
{
    public abstract void Bar();
}

public class Foo1 : FooBase
{
    public override void Bar()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

public class Foo2 : FooBase
{
    public override void Bar()
    {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```